# Next/Previous Entry Linking + Structure showing entry from different channel

Tags: channel-entries, structure, navigation, entryid

I have entry linking working in multiple templates on my current EE site. In one of my channels, when I get to the end of the loop, it's displaying a next link to an entry in a different channel. It is the next sequencial entry ID though. There isn't a previous link when i'm at the first entry in the loop. The entry that is displaying in the in correct channel shares the same parent page.

**Here's my structure hierarchy**

```
About Us
 - Leadership
   - has listing entries that have next/previous entry linking. Last entry has entry_id 106

 - Galleries
   - Video Galleries
     - Page 1 Child page with entry_id 107
     - Page 2
```

**Next/Previous entry linking logic**

```
<p class="next_prev_nav">
    {exp:channel:prev_entry channel="leadership"}
            <a href="/about-us/senior-leadership/{url_title}" title="{title}">Previous</a>
    {/exp:channel:prev_entry}

    {exp:channel:next_entry channel="leadership}
            <a href="/about-us/senior-leadership/{url_title}" title="{title}">Next</a>
    {/exp:channel:next_entry}
</p>
```

I tried to just do a quick hack and add entry_id="not 107" on the next_entry tag but that broke the next link for all listing pages. Entry ID 107 has it's own channel for videos, so it's not a rogue entry. Any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running the latest of both Structure and EE?

Comment: @TravisSchmeisser both are up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix: a quote was missing:

**Bad**

{exp:channel:next_entry channel="leadership}
        Next
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

**Good**

{exp:channel:next_entry channel="leadership"}
        Next
{/exp:channel:next_entry}